# Send a message to a offline user from a group chat in a SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I haven't started to write the code for my chat application yet and I am looking at some samples. I was thinking and reading about what to do if the target user is offline.

If the message is to one group, I don´t know how to determine which users are offline at that moment and didn't receive the message.

To identify a private chat (from samples):

```
    public SendMessage(string message, string targetUserName)
    {
        var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (HubHelper.IsConnected(targetUserName))
        {
            Clients.User(targetUserName).sendMessage(message);
        }
        else
        {
            DataAccess.InsertPendingMessage(userName, targetUserName, message);
        }
    }
```

In my case, I will have only one big group with all users (online and offline). How can I determine which users are offline at a particular point in time?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not care about online/offline users. Store every message and notify all subscribed users for that group that a new message is available. The client will then load the message whenever it is possible. And when going online the client just query the subscribed groups for new messages

Comment: @SirRufo But in this case i will have duplicated messages sometimes. I have to give a ID to the messages, store them and when user online query the DB, i check if the last ID´s of message are the same. Is this ?

Comment: I see you got the point. Each message has a unique id and a RowVersion (see MSSQL). The client only has to ask for all messages for the user with a RowVersion greater than the RowVersion from the last call

Comment: I will check about this rowversion. But i can check the timestamp also... When is a private chat, is easy because i can read and delete... in a group chat, when i think about, sounds more complicated and i can check the time for message or the rowversion that you are telling me...
Thanks for the "light"... regards!